# Asking my manager why I was not promoted

Tags: software-industry, communication, promotion

I have been working with a IT company for 3 years with the same title and salary. This year I was supposed to get a promotion but it did not happen.

How can I ask my manager for the reason behind it?

Comment: "Hey, boss, there was talk of a promotion this year, what happened?"

Comment: you should be getting review meetings with your supervisor every 6-12 months - if you haven't had one recently, ask for one

Comment: This will come off as rude, but this question seems appropriately timed with the latest Dilbert theme: http://dilbert.com/strip/2015-04-29

Comment: Under what pretense were you "supposed" to get a job?  In a contract?  In a review of your previous performance?  In casual conversation?  This makes a world of difference both in how to bring it up, and whether or not you actually have any power to complain about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This year I was supposed to get a promotion but it did not happen.
>
> How can I ask my manager for the reason behind it?

Ask your manager for a quick private discussion.

Explain why you feel that you were supposed to get a promotion. If you have any written documentation or emails to that effect, bring them. Then, ask why you haven't yet been promoted and when you might now expect one.

Discuss enough so that you understand the answer.

If it's something you are doing that you should change, work hard to change it. If it's something that you haven't done that you should, then do it.

If something in the business environment has changed such that your promotion is no longer viable, then you might need to resign yourself to the fact that you won't be promoted.

Recently, you indicated in another post that you don't have enough work and that you have a new manager. Perhaps the facts are all related? Perhaps your new manager wasn't the one who indicated you were "supposed to get a promotion"?

Answer (score 0):

> This year I was supposed to get a promotion but it did not happen

- You had regular 1-2-1s with you manager to check your progress/get feedback?
- You had clear, measurable goals to achieve to get the promotion?
- You solicited and documented feedback to show you met these goals?
- You got involved in additional activities/initiatives to make things better and show how important you are to the company/team?
- You ensured you got visibility across the division/company on successful projects (or help turned unsuccessful ones round)?

No?  You didn't take ownership of the process, and that's why you didn't get promoted.  You don't get promoted for doing your job well, you get it for being bigger than your role.

Comment: I agree: to go beyond your role is the definition of being promoted, and it's up to each of us to make sure we stand out. Don't waste your career waiting for a manager in shining armor to recognise your under-utilised talent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing this backwards. You've been in a position for 3 years and never bothered to find out what it takes to get promoted. What did you expect?

Since you didn't get the promotion this time, you still need to ask. They may say, you need to do 'blank' and you may feel you did that. I don't think this is a good time to argue your past accomplishments. Try to get your manager to set a time to review your progress on the things needed to get promoted. Start making connections on those goals and you recent accomplishments. Don't wait for some end of year evaluation. Get frequent feedback. You want your supervisor thinking you're doing what you need to do to get promoted.

You may find the company just can't afford to promote you at this time. That would be a shame. Make sure you're in a position to get the promotion when the time comes.